# After pause menu score doesn't work anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

does anyone know how to fix this? In my unity game when I go to pause menu and then continue playing, my scoreboard stops updating. I have two scoreboards, one in game and one in pause menu. The one in pause menu works well and updates but the one in game freezes after once visited in pause menu.

Here is my pausecodes and codes to add money (score):

```
    public void PauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    public void UnPauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;       
    }
    }
```

```
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Respawn") // When player lifts fish up
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            // TODO: Player gets money (points) when this happens
            textManager.instance.AddMoney();
            Debug.Log("Add money");
        }
```

```
public class textManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static textManager instance;

    public Text moneyText;

    public int money;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Data data = SaveSystem.LoadData();
        
        money = data.balance;

        moneyText.text = "Balance: " + money.ToString() + " $";
    }

    public void AddMoney()
    {
        money = money + 10;
        moneyText.text = "Balance: " + money.ToString() + " $";

        SaveSystem.SaveData(this);
    }

    public int findMoney()
    {
        return money;
    }
}
```

Please ask more info if needed.

I have tried to delete the one scoreboard in pause menu and after that the in-game pause menu started working right, but I would like to have still that other scoreboard too.

Comment: But when are you **PauseGame** and **UnPauseGame** the game ? how can people help you if you don't show the part where the actual problem is you said it doesn't update when you unpause the game after being paused you should confirm that you are unpausing the game first!!

Comment: Ah and by the way after the `Destroy(this.gameObject);` the code below will never be executed because you are destroying the script before even executing the code so I advice you to change the order of your code !!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Respawn") // When player lifts fish up
    {
       // TODO: Player gets money (points) when this happens
        textManager.instance.AddMoney();
        Debug.Log("Add money");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
     
    }
```

As I said this is the fix for what you posted as for the pause unpause problem you have to post the actual code where you do the pause unpause behavior so can people help you out my friend. As for what you posted what you've been doing is  destroying the script just before excuting the call to `textManager.instance.AddMoney();` and this will never run in the order you set in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a `static` field is global, this means there can only be one.
Your `textManager` (side note: a classes first letter has to be upper case) is certainly attached to multiple GameObjects, once to the object displaying the score in the scene UI and once to a UI element in the pause menu.
As soon as you pause your game the first time, the `TextManager` attached to the object in the pause menu will run Awake() and the `instance` (please capitalise your properties as well) will be overriden and the reference to the ingame `TextManager` gets discarded.

The sloppy fix is re-initializing the ingame `TextManager` when you unpause the game, assigning it to be the `Instance` again. I'd not recommend doing that though.

The better solution is to implement an event on the player that gets triggered when the score changes and making the player instance a Singleton object since there will be only one player in all circumstances.
The UI elements displaying the score can then subscribe to this event in `OnEnable()` and unsubscribe in `OnDisable()` (do not forget to unsubscribe from events).

Addendum: You should not destroy your object before all code has been executed. Your code will still work because of how things are managed on the C++ layer of Unity, but it is definitely bad practice.